# How Generate Dynamic carousel on div with images fetch from an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I am trying to generate a dynamic banner carousel and inside that, I want to append the images that I fetched from through an API. Data is coming in the console but unable to append it.

How to append it inside the Image tag and generate the dynamic div accordingly?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.6.1/async.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>
            console.log("hiiii");
            $(document).ready(function () {
                console.log("inside api...");
                getDatafromDocLib();
            });

            function getDatafromDocLib(){
                console.log("Inside api call-----------------");

                var doclibUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Demobannerlib')/Files";
                console.log("URL--------------------",doclibUrl);

               $.ajax({
                   url : doclibUrl,
                   type: 'GET',
                   headers : {
                       "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                   },
                   success : function(response){

                       console.log("---------Response---Data--------",response);

                       var length = response.d.results.length;

                       var data = response.d.results;
                       displayCarousel(data);
                   },
                   error: function(error){
                       console.log("error in getting data from library", error);
                   }
               });

            }

            function displayCarousel(data){
                console.log("data inside display function....", data);
                for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){

                    $("<div>")
                    .addClass('iviewer_image_mask')
                    .css('background', "url('https://dimensiondata3.sharepoint.com/c2sd3/India/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/c2sd3/India/Demobannerlib/img55.jpg')')")
                    .appendTo("#slideshow-container");  
                }
            }



        </script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <h2>NTT<h2>
                <div class="slideshow-container">

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <img src="https://dimensiondata3.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/Bannerlib/img1.jpg?csf=1&e=J0Wq9J"
                            style="width:100%">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <img
                            src="https://dimensiondata3.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/Bannerlib/img4.jpg?csf=1&e=c8q9aX">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <img src="https://dimensiondata3.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/Bannerlib/img2.jpg?csf=1&e=986eez"
                            style="width:100%">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <br>

                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                </div>

                <script>
                    var slideIndex = 0;
                    showSlides();
                    function showSlides() {
                        var i;
                        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                            slides[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                        slideIndex++;
                        if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
                        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                        }
                        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
                        setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
                    }
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Data in the console. I want to append these images inside my div.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes in your displayCarousel function:

```
  function displayCarousel(data){
            console.log("data inside display function....", data);
            for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
              var  img_url =  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '' + data[i].ServerRelativeUrl;
              var img_div = '<div class="mySlides fade"><img src="'+img_url+'"> </div>';
              $("#slideshow-container").append(img_div);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thansk for replying rishab..hope it will work. bhai 2 din se yahi task kar raha hu...

Comment: do i have to remove the div that with the hardcoded img URL

Comment: Yes you should remove it, so it will only show the dynamic image from js code

Comment: It is not working, images are not coming, in the console i'm getting an error  https://dimensiondata3.sharepoint.com/c2sd3/India/c2sd3/India/Demobannerlib/img11.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: Check whether you have access to that url public, make the image accessible so it wont give error

Comment: HI rishab, i do have access to URL publicly but images are displaying...

Comment: Enter Image url here which is generated

Comment: I have appended the image URL .... after the app web URL... but still it is not working....

Comment: Please add the URL code of image here we will check to open it in our browser

Comment: function displayCarousel(data) {
                console.log("data inside display function....", data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    ///var img_url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '' + data.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl;
                    var img_url = "https://dimensiondata3.sharepoint.com"+data.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl;
                    var img_div = '<div class="mySlides fade"><img src="' + img_url + '"> </div>';
                    $("#slideshow-container").append(img_div);
                }
            }

Comment: https://dimensiondata3.sharepoint.com/c2sd3/India/c2sd3/India/Demobannerlib/img11.jpg

This link is not visible at our end it requires microsoft login to view it

Comment: I got it, i have added wrong CSS, .mySlides {
                display: none;
            },  bcoz of this the images are not displaying.... thanx for the Answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get the banner element by Id.
then update the innerHTML

```
var el = document.getElementById("banner");
el.innerHTML="<img src=\"http://placehold.it/350x350\">";
```

or Try

```
 var el = document.getElementById("id for banner img");
 el.src="url";
```

Comment: I have tried this Thomas but the images is not displying, what changes needs to do.... Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you make sure the <img/> has height and width inside the dom